# Read a list of nonnegative integers and to display the largest integer, the smallest integer and the average of all the integers

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

I have encountered some problems with the calculating of largest and smallest number... If the first number I entered is a larger number than the 2nd number input, it will not record the 1st number into the largest...

Take a look at the output, it will help elaborate better..
[Calculation Error..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rge84.jpg) & 
[1st input problem..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nl2y7.jpg)
Codes below!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int largest = 0;
    int number;
    double totalAvg = 0;
    double totalSum = 0;
    int count = 0;

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter few integers (Enter negative numbers to end input) :");
    while (true) { //LOOP till user enter "-1"
        number = kb.nextInt();

        //Condition for the loop to break
        if (number <= -1) {
            System.out.println("End Of Input");
            break;
        } else {
            count = count + 1;
        }

        if (number < smallest) { //Problem 1 : If 1st input num is bigger than 2nd input num,
            smallest = number;  // largest num will not be recorded..
        } else {
            largest = number;
        }

        totalSum = totalSum + number;
        totalAvg = (totalSum / count);

    }

    System.out.println("The smallest number you have entered is : " + smallest);
    System.out.println("The largest number you have entered is : " + largest);
    System.out.println("The total sum is : " + totalSum);
    System.out.println("The total average is : " + totalAvg);
    System.out.println("Count : " + count);
} // PSVM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int largest = 0;
int number;
double totalAvg = 0;
double totalSum = 0;
int count = 0;

Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter few integers (Enter negative numbers to end input) :");
while (true) { //LOOP till user enter "-1"
    number = kb.nextInt();

    //Condition for the loop to break
    if (number <= -1) {
        System.out.println("End Of Input");
        break;
    } else {
        count = count + 1;
    }

    if (number < smallest) { //Problem 1 : If 1st input num is bigger than 2nd input num,
        smallest = number;  // largest num will not be recorded..
    }

    //REMOVED ELSE ADDED another IF

    if (number > largest){
        largest = number;
    }

    totalSum = totalSum + number;
    totalAvg = (totalSum / count);

}

System.out.println("The smallest number you have entered is : " + smallest);
System.out.println("The largest number you have entered is : " + largest);
System.out.println("The total sum is : " + totalSum);
System.out.println("The total average is : " + totalAvg);
System.out.println("Count : " + count);
} // PSVM
```

Comment: Oh my god... I spent 1hour trying to figure out what happened and its such a silly mistake.. Thank god you helped me.. God bless you, thanks mate!!

Comment: Thnxx Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

You could build an `IntStream` if you are using **Java 8**, and extract those numbers automatically using `IntSummaryStatistics`. You can find the official documentation from Oracle [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html).

Here is the code to achieve that:

```
    List<Integer> input = new ArrayList<>(); 
    while (true) { // LOOP till user enter "-1"
        number = kb.nextInt();

        // Condition for the loop to break
        if (number <= -1) {
            System.out.println("End Of Input");
            break;
        } else {
            input.add(number);
        }
    }
    IntSummaryStatistics z = input.stream() // gives Stream<Integer>
            .mapToInt(Integer::intValue) // gives IntStream
            .summaryStatistics(); // gives you the IntSummaryStatistics
    System.out.println(z);
```

If you input `8 3 7` the output will be:

```
IntSummaryStatistics{count=3, sum=18, min=3, average=6.000000, max=8}
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your if statement, as the logic is flawed. If the input number is smaller than smallest, then you update the smallest number. So far all is correct. The problem occurs, because you update largest in the else part. This means, if a number is not the smallest, largest is overwritten. But if the number is greater than the smallest, it is not automatically the largest. The right way to do this, is to check if the number is larger than the largest in a new if statement and update largest only in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your help Leon! :-D